# How to loop over an ArrayList using the index value of an Array (Processing)

Tags: processing

The second loop (for (int j = years[i].xrateValue.size ()-1; j >= 0; j--)) is retrieving all the xrate values for each Year from the array (years[i]). Please do you have any ideas of how I can only return the xrate values for each year in the array. For example, Year 1990 has Xrate 2,5,6,5.6 and Year 1991 has Xrate 3,6.7,5,8,1.4. The loop should only return the Xrate values for 1990 and then 1991 and so on.

```
for (int i=0; i<years.length; i++)
  {
    //code to display each year

    for (int j = years[i].xrateValue.size ()-1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
      float xrate = (float)(years[i].xrateValue.get(j));
      float barHeight = map(xrate, 0, mathMax, 0, 80); //adjust rect size
      float bX = sX+2;
      float bY = sY + 105 - barHeight;
      float bW = 105 / years.length;
      strokeWeight(0.9);
      stroke(10);
      fill(255, 8, 8);
      if (xrate >= 71)
      {
        fill(2, 152, 48);
      } else if ((xrate >= 51) && (xrate <= 70))
      {         
        fill(255, 217, 19);
      }
      rect(i+i+i+bX, bY, bW, barHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is years? An array, an object ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the loop should only return"? Return to where?

Comment: Year is an object that has an ArrayList (xrateValue) which holds all the xrate for each year. I want the loop to go over each year and then return the corresponding x rate i.e. 1990 [2,5,6,5.6] and 1991 [3,6.7,5,8,1.4] etc

Comment: @FolexIT We don't get notifications about your comment unless you tag us in them. But again, what do you mean by "return"? You can only return something from a function- and then, you can only return one thing, not multiple things. You can get around this by returning an array or an ArrayList, but so far you haven't really explained what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i : [listname]){
    for(int j = i; j > 0; j--){
        // your code
    }
}
```

This repeats a repitition that repeats 1 extra time each time the repitition repeats (Wow that's confusing. just read it over untill it makes sense.).