# For loop/Array/Collections

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, processing

I am trying to return only the xrate (which has a float types) for each Year. year.length is the maximum length of i and the locationTable contains unique values for each YEAR i.e. 1990, 1991, 1992 etc. The dataTable has a year column but it is not unique because each YEAR has between 4 and 9 xrate values. The if statement within the second loop is checking if a YEAR in the unique locationTable is present in the YEAR within the dataTable. 
If this is true, how can I return only the xrate values in the corresponding YEAR in the dataTable?

```
  for (int i=0; i<years.length; i++)
  {
    String bName = locationTable.getString(i, "YEAR");
    years[i] = new Year(bName);

    for (int k=0; k<dataTable.getRowCount (); k++)
    {
      String sName = dataTable.getString(k, "YEAR");

      if (bName.equals(sName))
      {
        xrate= dataTable.getFloat(k, "XRATE"); // this is the problem
      }
    }
```

Currently, when I use the print function it returns all the xrate values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to loop over an ArrayList using the index value of an Array (Processing)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234996/how-to-loop-over-an-arraylist-using-the-index-value-of-an-array-processing)

Comment: Like I said [the first time you posted this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234996/how-to-loop-over-an-arraylist-using-the-index-value-of-an-array-processing), it doesn't make any sense to "return" something multiple times from a loop. You either have to build an ArrayList or an array and return that, or you have to be more specific about what you're trying to return.

Comment: I want to return only the xrate for each year and use it in a bar chart

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "return for each year"? You can only return a single value from a function. Have you tried building an array or ArrayList of xrate values and returning that?

Comment: One bar chart for each year. I used an ArrayList but it returns for Year 1990 [1.3, 4.5, 6.7, 8.9, 8,0] [1.3, 4.5, 6.7, 8.9, 8,0] [1.3, 4.5, 6.7, 8.9, 8,0] [1.3, 4.5, 6.7, 8.9, 8,0] [1.3, 4.5, 6.7, 8.9, 8,0]

Comment: for (int j = years[i].xRate.size ()-1; j >= 0; j--) 
    {
      println(years[i].xRate);
      noLoop();
    }

Comment: Where xRate is an ArrayList to hold all the xrate values

Comment: And what do you want to do with that ArrayList?

Comment: I want to use it as values to set the height of the bar chart for each year

Comment: Okay, and how do you do that? Maybe you're trying to build an ArrayList of ArrayLists?

Comment: That what I am trying to achieve with the code I shared above and loop (for (int j = years[i].xRate.size ()-1; j >= 0; j--) { println(years[i].xRate); noLoop(); }) inside the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Not having your data sets, or much context for your code, I have only one guess: I think when you create `bname` in the first part of the loop, your if statement below will always be true.